# how to not display a sum with value 0 with views aggergation plus module

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm using [views aggregation plus module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator), doing group and compress from taxonomy fields and haveing a columns sum action, how can i hide sums with zero value? [views conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) do not have any effect,  also i tryed all 'no results behaviour' settings. Code or hooks are welcome, any help will be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Which "No results behaviour" did you try? The one in the field settings with the options `Count the number 0 as empty` and `Hide if empty`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/8htgyJW, all of them, i check/uncheck one by one, i also disable styles in views aggregation settings, and styles inside each field, non worked. i'm almost there, i added a views-view-myfield.tpl.php and placed this code inside: $valor = $row->field_field_ldescuento_promo_mes_monto[0]['raw']['value'];
$cero = 0;
if ($valor > $cero) {
  print $output;
} but i get this warning: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 en include() (línea 39

Comment: solution posted in my previous comment it works, data is fetched, but it stills display warnings, i had to disable 'warning' messages, and i do not like that, any help fetching 'raw value of a sum field' will be very appreciated.